# Как добавить высоту и ширину блоку в html на чистом JS?

Tags: javascript

Как при нажатии кнопки `.b-1`, которая запускает функцию `f1`, присвоить блоку `.out-1` ширину 200px, высоту 40px ?

Вот что у меня получилось сделать:

HTML:

```
<button class="b-1">B-1</button>
<div class="out-1"></div>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector('.b-1').onclick = f1 () {
    let block1 = document.querySelector('.out-1').classList.add('')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function f1(){
  let block1 = document.querySelector('.out-1');
  block1.style.width = '200px';
  block1.style.height = '40px';
}

document.querySelector('.b-1').addEventListener( 'click', f1 );
```

```css
.out-1 {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<button class="b-1">B-1</button>
<div class="out-1">123</div>
```